# Git reset and delete branch not reverting back properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I created a new branch called user-microposts.  I proceeded to mess something up on creating a model.  I tried going back to the last commit using:

```
git reset --hard cb166caa1c70004f77eed6229168b06ad249a4ba
```

which gave back:

```
HEAD is now at cb166ca Eliminate an unnecessary assignment
```

So I tried redoing the Migrate, which gave me this error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "microposts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "microposts"
....
```

I was surprised because I thought if I went back to the previous commit, it would be like nothing happened.

So I reverted back to master branch and deleted the branch in which I made any changes.

I then created a new branch, and tried to create another model and run rake db:migrate.  Again I got the same error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: table "microposts" already exists: CREATE TABLE "microposts"
....
```

I recently tried to manually delete any file with microposts in it.  Again with no such luck.

I keep getting the same error.  I thought the purpose of both the git branch and/or git reset would prevent this scenario, so I am very confused.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just a tip: when reseting branches, use relative names, not absolute ones. If you want to rollback one commit, do `git reset --hard HEAD^`. If you want to rollback three commits, do `git reset --hard HEAD~3`.

Comment: As for your actual question, is git tracking your SQLite database? It sounds like it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be unusual for your database to be under source control.  Thus, if you revert your source you will likely have inconsistencies between the database and the source.  The solution has a few options:

1. delete the database and recreate it
2. rollback the database to match the source

For both of the above you'd use the typical 'rake db' type commands.

Comment: I see -Thank you.  I was able to get it to work by doing the following - first typing: sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 

sqlite> drop table table_name;

sqlite> .quit

Comment: Right, that was essentially recreating the database.